# Comparing normal distributions using a two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: normal-distribution, parametric

I have used a two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare the distributions of two sets of data. I know that the K-S test is a non parametric test, however the distributions of data I'm comparing has turned out to be normally distributed...

I know there is probably a number of tests that could be used to compare normally distributed data, but is there a reason not to use the K-S test? Are there any disadvantages (with regard to type1 and 2 errors perhaps)? Is it ok to use it?

I've sort of gone down this route with my data analysis, but the question has come up: why use a non parametric test to compare parametric data? Hopefully K-S is unconventional rather than completely wrong.

Advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You would likely get a deeper pool of expert Readers at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get a satisfactory Answer here.  Perhaps you could update your Question with how much is known or suspected about the normality of the two normal populations, e.g. equal means, different variances, unknown parameters.

Comment: Rob has [reposted this Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111842/comparing-normal-distributions-using-a-two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test) at CrossValidated; voting to close.